# Custom HDRP Shader flickers colors

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, flicker

I needed to create a lit HDRP Shader with an override property for the base color value. But my shader seems to do very strange things.

Some examples and the shader graph can be found here : https://postimg.cc/gallery/VvzFsSG

Do you have any idead what i need to look for ? I set the ColorOverride property only once in my code when i am creating an entity (i am using ecs).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I had something like this when rather than assigning a name I had also named the underlying variable.

Comment: So you mean i unwantedly override the default "_Color" and the override value ?

Comment: Dunno I think I had a parameter of say firstcolour and i did nothing else. And got psychotic behavior. Someone then said click on the details of the parameter and give it a name but not like a perused one like colour so we tried Fred. Suddenly it all worked.

Comment: Unfortunately not for me. Changed all to _ColorOverrideValue and it did not help.

Comment: Im not in front of unity. Which bit are you changing the visible name or the underlying property name which is usually gibberish and hidden from us?

Comment: Sorry for answering late : both. Tried setting the reference, the name, renaming the reference and changing that. 
UPDATE: The flickering was gone after i disabled the srp batcher. But now the values are not set. The color override component is set properly but it won't set the value on the material. I also tried using the built in MaterialColor component but with the same effect. Material is set to gpu instantiatable and the shader property to per-instance.